# Differentiate between client connections with node?

Tags: node.js, http, client-server

I need to implement a server that can handle simultaneous connections from both a client app and a browser that share a common database, however the clients from the browser have different functions from the clients of the app. I would like suggestions if this is the best design implementation. I decided not to have a different server for the client app or from the browser for this same reason as I can foreshadow synchronization issues when retrieving/writing information form the database. Is there a way to somehow attach a string or other information in front of the http connection to be able to tell each apart?

when the connection is made to the server what should be done?

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response)

{
//Code to tell them apart




});
```

Comment: Just use a different path on the URL for each separate request.  That's what the path is for - to tell the server what the specific request is.  then, use separate routes for each path to direct the server to different code for each path.

Answer (score 0):

Your client app is the best place to start. Do you have control over the client app? If you can modify it to send a specific header, that may work. Otherwise, another way to do so is to differentiate between User Agents... If the client app will always have a specific UA, treat all requests with that UA as a client app request, and all others as a browser request.